# React Native : Modal closing functionality

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am currently following the modal example given here.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

The code works and it is indeed showing a modal box.

But there is no "close" functionality except the one via TouchableHighlight onPress event.

Is it possible to have a "close modal" functionality via "X" on the corner ?

I checked out the props and I am not able to find any.

So does this mean that using only the TouchableHighlight's onPress event alone you will be able to control the modal's closing ?

**App.js code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Text, TouchableHighlight, View } from 'react-native';

export default class ModalExample extends Component {

  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
          >
         <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
          <View>
            <Text>Hello World!</Text>

            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
              this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
            }}>
              <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

          </View>
         </View>
        </Modal>

        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
          this.setModalVisible(true)
        }}>
          <Text>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've recently used (in production) and found [this](https://github.com/raynor85/react-native-modal-wrapper) library to be super useful for modal. It extends on top of the native Modal class, giving you additional functionality such as swipe-gestures. Do check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Text, TouchableHighlight, View } from 'react-native';

export default class ModalExample extends Component {

  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  closeModal = () => {
      this.setState({modalVisible: false})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
          >
         <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>

          <View>
            <Text>Hello World!</Text>

            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
              this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
            }}>
              <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
         <CloseButton onPress={this.closeModal} /> // Create your 'X' button with your preferred styling
         </View>
        </Modal>

        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
          this.setModalVisible(true)
        }}>
          <Text>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You just need to add a button to the modal with your preferred styling and on the button's onPress listener set the state variable `modalVisible` to `false` for hiding the modal.